# ASP.NET MVC Model Binding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

I was wondering if there was a way to bind the value of an input field straight to the property in the Model through a strongly typed model.  For example, let's say my Model is an Address object.  I want to be able to say `Html.Textbox(Model.Address1.State, "state", Model.Address1.State)`.  So the first parameter would be the explicit property I want to bind to of the model with the value from the user, the second parameter would just be the DOM id, and the third value would be the initial value to input when I render the view.

I know you can do `Html.TextBox("Address.State")` and have a custom binder which would create the Address object for you and populate the state property. I need `Html.Textbox(Model.Address1.State)`.

Help?

Comment: Are you asking to do something like:

<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress) %>

Comment: Yes, precisely.  I keep seeing Html.TextBoxFor.  Where is this from?

Comment: MVC 2.0 (currently in Beta) http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/asp.net-mvc-2-beta-released.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think the [FluentHtml](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FluentHtml&referringTitle=Documentation) stuff from the [mvccontrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib) code is what you may want to check out.